# How to take a screenshot of the current MapView?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have two buttons and a mapView. I want to save the MapView's view when I press one of the buttons.

Anyone got any idea about how I can do this?

Comment: I dont try nothing not know where to start

Comment: Then search for it. come with an implementation which doesn't work. Then people will be helping you.

Comment: Thanks for all Venky,
Thanks too RivieraKid for edit my post. Im too newbie here i've to learn to use it well.
Andro Selva the last time i promise. Sorry for all.

Answer (score 5):

You have to add a listener to the button (you should know how this done) and in that listener, do something like that:

```
boolean enabled = mMapView.isDrawingCacheEnabled();
mMapView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bm = mMapView.getDrawingCache();

/* now you've got the bitmap - go save it */

File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
path = new File(path, "Pictures");
path.mkdirs();  // make sure the Pictures folder exists.
File file = new File(path, "filename.png");
BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
boolean success = bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();

mMapView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(enabled);   // reset to original value
```

In order to have the image show up in the Gallery immediately, you have to notify the MediaScanner about the new image like so:

```
if (success) {
    MediaScannerClientProxy client = new MediaScannerClientProxy(file.getAbsolutePath(), "image/png");
    MediaScannerConnection msc = new MediaScannerConnection(this, client);
    client.mConnection = msc;
    msc.connect();
}
```

Comment: This does not work for the V2 Google Mapview. It just retruns a blank screen with only the zoom buttons visible.

Comment: @Mannaz I know and I have no idea how to do it with V2. They use a Surface View there and so far I only found information that it is not possible to get the content of a Surface view as a bitmap. Also the V2 API does not provide anything to achieve it.

Comment: And although I understand that you're disappointed, the downvote is not very fair, as the answer is from a time where no V2 API was around.

Comment: Works fine for osmdroid mapview, if anyone looking for screenshot of Google Maps V2 implement SnapshotReadyCallback.

Answer (score 3):

google map have a function to take a snapshot so use this here is example, it return a bitmap that you can set on a image view its simple..

```
Bitmap bitmapMapsattelite ;

map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapLoaded() {
                            // Make a snapshot when map's done loading
                            map.snapshot(new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {
                                    bitmapMapsattelite = null;
                                    /// make the bitmap null so everytime it //will fetch the new bitmap 
                                    bitmapMapsattelite = bitmap;

                                }

                            });
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I used in this way to take only fragment screen using OSMDroid.

```
private void captureScreen() {

    // put captureScreen() inside your OSMDroid fragment
    // it's better put a button inside your layout OSMDroid fragment.xml

    view = view.findViewById(R.id.mapview); //using OSMDroid fragment to call <org.osmdroid.views.MapView/>

    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());

    //build your folder
    File sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ArqueoMaquina");
    if (!sd.exists()) {
        sd.mkdir();
    }

    File imagePath = new File(sd , "mapa" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
    FileOutputStream fos;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imagePath); //to take the file path to your .png map saved in your phone

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Those are the results. My screen App with OSMDroid fragment and Button "Save Map":
[image]

And my map.png saved in folder phone showing only the OSMDroid fragment:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The required functionality was introduced in Osmdroid 6.1.0. The corresponding class is [MapSnapshot](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/drawing/MapSnapshot.java).

For the use case in the question adding the below code in the click callback of the button would work.

```java
final MapSnapshot mapSnapshot = new MapSnapshot(new MapSnapshot.MapSnapshotable() {
            @Override
            public void callback(final MapSnapshot pMapSnapshot) {
                if (pMapSnapshot.getStatus() != MapSnapshot.Status.CANVAS_OK) {
                    return;
                }
                final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pMapSnapshot.getBitmap());
                // Do something with the bitmap like save to file
            }
        }, MapSnapshot.INCLUDE_FLAG_UPTODATE, pMapView);
new Thread(mapSnapshot).start();
```

Reference : https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1737

Answer (score 0):

Google map has a call back named snapshot -> map.snapshot that return a Bitmap to handling.
In osmdroid (open street map android api), corresponding method is getDrawingCache method -> map.getDrawingCache